# Gradle include Maven

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I found a library on Github which I want to include into my Android project (I use Android Studio) which uses Maven for distribution. Unfortunately I could not figure out how to include this library with Gradle given the Mavens pom.xml file additions on the Github page:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.japgolly.android</groupId>
  <artifactId>svg-android</artifactId>
<version>2.0.6</version>
```

The Github Page is https://github.com/japgolly/svg-android

My build.gradle file (which does not work out) so far:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tg.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://github.com/japgolly/svg-android' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile 'svg-android:2.0.6'
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

`compile 'com.github.japgolly.android:svg-android:2.0.6'`